# AWS EC2 Will Not Connect to DynamoDB using static Access Credentials

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, aws-sdk

I am using AWS DynamoDB for the first time and having some problems with it running on an EC2 instance.  I reviewed the AWS examples and found a simple Java CRUD example.  I got it working very quickly using Eclipse Java Spring Boot and AWS DynamoDB running in the cloud.  I ran it on my desktop using static access credentials.  I had to include in the applications.properties page,  "cloud.aws.region.static = us-west-2".  It accessed the AWS Cloud-based DynamoDB service with no problems.  I then commented out the "cloud.aws.region.static = us-west-2" and ran the exact same Java Spring-Boot microservice on an EC2 instance.  I got a number of errors but all seem to point to an inability to access DynamoDB credential provider chain.  I know static credentials are not the recommended approach for security reasons but I don't understand why this is not working.  Any ideas?

Application Code:

```
package com.belcan;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException;
import com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException;
import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSStaticCredentialsProvider;
import com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDB;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.AttributeDefinition;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.AttributeValue;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.ComparisonOperator;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.Condition;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.CreateTableRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.DescribeTableRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.KeySchemaElement;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.KeyType;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.ProvisionedThroughput;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.PutItemRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.PutItemResult;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.ScalarAttributeType;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.ScanRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.ScanResult;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.TableDescription;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.util.TableUtils;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DynamoDbExampleWarApplication {


    static String awsaccesskeyid = "bla-bla-bal";
    static String awssecretkey = "yadi-yadi-yada";

    static AmazonDynamoDB dynamoDB;

    public static void init() {

        try {

            BasicAWSCredentials myCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(awsaccesskeyid, awssecretkey);
            dynamoDB = AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard()
                .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(myCredentials))
                .withRegion("us-west-2")
                .build();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new AmazonClientException(
                    "Init1(): Cannot load the credentials from the credential profiles file. " + toString.e);
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DynamoDbExampleWarApplication.class, args);

            // Get Amazon DynamoDB Client
            init();

            try {
                String tableName = "my-favorite-movies-table";

                // Create a table with a primary hash key named 'name', which holds a string
                CreateTableRequest createTableRequest = new CreateTableRequest().withTableName(tableName)
                    .withKeySchema(new KeySchemaElement().withAttributeName("name").withKeyType(KeyType.HASH))
                    .withAttributeDefinitions(new AttributeDefinition().withAttributeName("name").withAttributeType(ScalarAttributeType.S))
                    .withProvisionedThroughput(new ProvisionedThroughput().withReadCapacityUnits(1L).withWriteCapacityUnits(1L));

                // Create table if it does not exist yet
                TableUtils.createTableIfNotExists(dynamoDB, createTableRequest);
                // wait for the table to move into ACTIVE state
                try {
                TableUtils.waitUntilActive(dynamoDB, tableName);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Table Error");
                }
                // Describe our new table
                DescribeTableRequest describeTableRequest = new DescribeTableRequest().withTableName(tableName);
                TableDescription tableDescription = dynamoDB.describeTable(describeTableRequest).getTable();
                System.out.println("Table Description: " + tableDescription);

                // Add an item
                Map<String, AttributeValue> item = newItem("Bill & Ted's Excellent Adventure", 1989, "****", "James", "Sara");
                PutItemRequest putItemRequest = new PutItemRequest(tableName, item);
                PutItemResult putItemResult = dynamoDB.putItem(putItemRequest);

                System.out.println("Result: " + putItemResult);

                // Add another item
                item = newItem("Airplane", 1980, "*****", "James", "Billy Bob");
                putItemRequest = new PutItemRequest(tableName, item);
                putItemResult = dynamoDB.putItem(putItemRequest);
                System.out.println("Result: " + putItemResult);

                // Scan items for movies with a year attribute greater than 1985
                HashMap<String, Condition> scanFilter = new HashMap<String, Condition>();
                Condition condition = new Condition()
                    .withComparisonOperator(ComparisonOperator.GT.toString())
                    .withAttributeValueList(new AttributeValue().withN("1985"));
                scanFilter.put("year", condition);
                ScanRequest scanRequest = new ScanRequest(tableName).withScanFilter(scanFilter);
                ScanResult scanResult = dynamoDB.scan(scanRequest);
                System.out.println("Result: " + scanResult);



            } catch (AmazonServiceException ase) {
                System.out.println("Caught an AmazonServiceException, which means your request made it "
                        + "to AWS, but was rejected with an error response for some reason.");
                System.out.println("Error Message:    " + ase.getMessage());
                System.out.println("HTTP Status Code: " + ase.getStatusCode());
                System.out.println("AWS Error Code:   " + ase.getErrorCode());
                System.out.println("Error Type:       " + ase.getErrorType());
                System.out.println("Request ID:       " + ase.getRequestId());

            } catch (AmazonClientException ace) {
                System.out.println("Caught an AmazonClientException, which means the client encountered "
                        + "a serious internal problem while trying to communicate with AWS, "
                        + "such as not being able to access the network.");
                System.out.println("Error Message: " + ace.getMessage());
            }

    }   

       public static Map<String, AttributeValue> newItem(String name, int year, String rating, String... fans) {
            Map<String, AttributeValue> item = new HashMap<String, AttributeValue>();
            item.put("name", new AttributeValue(name));
            item.put("year", new AttributeValue().withN(Integer.toString(year)));
            item.put("rating", new AttributeValue(rating));
            item.put("fans", new AttributeValue().withSS(fans));

            return item;
        }   

}
```

Here is the EC2 Linux Error String,

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-0-244 server]$ java -jar DynamoDBExample-war-v001.war

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.5.9.RELEASE)


....Deleted a lot of messages to try to keep the message length as short as possible.


2017-12-20 15:03:32.187  INFO 7372 --- [           main] c.belcan.DynamoDbExampleWarApplication   : Starting DynamoDbExampleWarApplication on ip-10-0-0-244 with PID 7372 (/home/ec2-user/server/DynamoDBExample-war-v001.war started by ec2-user in /home/ec2-user/server)
2017-12-20 15:03:32.190  INFO 7372 --- [           main] c.belcan.DynamoDbExampleWarApplication   : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2017-12-20 15:03:32.243  INFO 7372 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@30946e09: startup date [Wed Dec 20 15:03:32 UTC 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-12-20 15:03:34.568  INFO 7372 --- [           main] o.s.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy          : Final method [protected final com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.InitiateMultipartUploadRequest com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.newInitiateMultipartUploadRequest(com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.UploadObjectRequest)] cannot get proxied via CGLIB: Calls to this method will NOT be routed to the target instance and might lead to 
2017-12-20 15:03:36.530  INFO 7372 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@30946e09: startup date [Wed Dec 20 15:03:32 UTC 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-12-20 15:03:36.616  INFO 7372 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2017-12-20 15:03:36.618  INFO 7372 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2017-12-20 15:03:36.657  INFO 7372 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-12-20 15:03:36.657  INFO 7372 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-12-20 15:03:36.707  INFO 7372 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-12-20 15:03:36.951  INFO 7372 --- [           main] b.a.s.AuthenticationManagerConfiguration :

Using default security password: 1cadad8f-e5f6-44ed-a2fd-6df59c36010a

2017-12-20 15:03:37.008  INFO 7372 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: OrRequestMatcher [requestMatchers=[Ant [pattern='/css/**'], Ant [pattern='/js/**'], Ant [pattern='/images/**'], Ant [pattern='/webjars/**'], Ant [pattern='/**/favicon.ico'], Ant [pattern='/error']]], []
2017-12-20 15:03:37.287  INFO 7372 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/dump || /dump.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2017-12-20 15:03:37.289  INFO 7372 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/metrics/{name:.*}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.MetricsMvcEndpoint.value(java.lang.String)
2017-12-20 15:03:37.290  INFO 7372 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/metrics || /metrics.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2017-12-20 15:03:37.290  INFO 7372 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/configprops || /configprops.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2017-12-20 15:03:37.291  INFO 7372 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/health || /health.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.HealthMvcEndpoint.invoke(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.security.Principal)
2017-12-20 15:03:37.292  INFO 7372 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/beans || /beans.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2017-12-20 15:03:37.294  INFO 7372 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/auditevents || /auditevents.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.AuditEventsMvcEndpoint.findByPrincipalAndAfterAndType(java.lang.String,java.util.Date,java.lang.String)
2017-12-20 15:03:37.297  INFO 7372 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/autoconfig || /autoconfig.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2017-12-20 15:03:37.300  INFO 7372 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/loggers/{name:.*}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.LoggersMvcEndpoint.get(java.lang.String)
2017-12-20 15:03:37.300  INFO 7372 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/loggers/{name:.*}],methods=[POST],consumes=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.LoggersMvcEndpoint.set(java.lang.String,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>)
2017-12-20 15:03:37.301  INFO 7372 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/loggers || /loggers.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2017-12-20 15:03:37.301  INFO 7372 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/heapdump || /heapdump.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/octet-stream]}" onto public void org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.HeapdumpMvcEndpoint.invoke(boolean,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) throws java.io.IOException,javax.servlet.ServletException
2017-12-20 15:03:37.302  INFO 7372 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/trace || /trace.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2017-12-20 15:03:37.303  INFO 7372 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/mappings || /mappings.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2017-12-20 15:03:37.310  INFO 7372 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/info || /info.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2017-12-20 15:03:37.313  INFO 7372 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/env/{name:.*}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EnvironmentMvcEndpoint.value(java.lang.String)
2017-12-20 15:03:37.313  INFO 7372 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Mapped "{[/env || /env.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2017-12-20 15:03:37.314  INFO 7372 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.ManagementWebSecurityAutoConfiguration$LazyEndpointPathRequestMatcher@5b94b04d, [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@8c3b9d, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@682b2fa, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@3fc2959f, org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter@4c39bec8, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@477b4cdf, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@3c9754d8, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@7dcf94f8, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@662ac478, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@f79e, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@6989da5e, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@6a78afa0, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@6ed3ccb2]
2017-12-20 15:03:37.317  INFO 7372 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: OrRequestMatcher [requestMatchers=[Ant [pattern='/**']]], [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@3af9c5b7, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@445b295b, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@2e377400, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@757277dc, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@687e99d8, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@49e5f737, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@5c671d7f, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@37271612, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@1757cd72, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@561b6512, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@10aa41f2]
2017-12-20 15:03:37.555  WARN 7372 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cloud.aws.core.env.ResourceIdResolver.BEAN_NAME': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'stackResourceRegistryFactoryBean' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/aws/autoconfigure/context/ContextStackAutoConfiguration$StackAutoDetectConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.aws.core.env.stack.config.StackResourceRegistryFactoryBean]: Factory method 'stackResourceRegistryFactoryBean' threw exception; nested exception is com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain
2017-12-20 15:03:37.556  INFO 7372 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
2017-12-20 15:03:37.560  INFO 7372 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2017-12-20 15:03:38.079  INFO 7372 --- [           main] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer :

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2017-12-20 15:03:38.086 ERROR 7372 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cloud.aws.core.env.ResourceIdResolver.BEAN_NAME': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'stackResourceRegistryFactoryBean' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/aws/autoconfigure/context/ContextStackAutoConfiguration$StackAutoDetectConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.aws.core.env.stack.config.StackResourceRegistryFactoryBean]: Factory method 'stackResourceRegistryFactoryBean' threw exception; nested exception is com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain


...Lot  more lines of error messages but I think you get the picture...

    [ec2-user@ip-10-0-0-244 server]$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like the Dynamo call is failing. it looks like Spring Cloud AWS is failing.

Here is the last portion of the stack trace you provided:

`Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.aws.core.env.stack.config.StackResourceRegistryFactoryBean]: Factory method 'stackResourceRegistryFactoryBean' threw exception; nested exception is com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain`

It looks like Spring Cloud AWS wants credentials, and providing them for only DynamoDB isn't enough.

Try removing Spring Cloud from your dependencies if you don't need it.

Comment: Wow, great catch on this one.  The problem threw out a lot of errors and I did not pick up on the org.springframework.cloud.aws... exception.  I commented out in the dependencies section  "compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-aws')" and it ran just fine.  Any inside secrets you can pass my way to catch similar things like this in the future?

Comment: Hey Mark, I am getting the feeling that the DynamoDB SDK is very poorly designed.  Is it me or have you had similar experiences?  I have been using MongoDB for the last year and thought I would try DynamoDB.  The MongoDB SDK is infinitely easier to use.  Your thoughts?